# Error de cáracter inválido en firebase.js

Tags: firebase, flutter, vscode

Al ejecutar cualquier comando de firebase desde la terminal de Visual Studio Code para mi proyecto de Flutter, obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: Error en firebase.js]

He intentado reinstalar firebase, pero no parece funcionar. Quisiera saber por qué se podría estar produciendo esto.

Comment: ¿Está instalado firebase? ¿Cómo lo instalaste?